# PLS-00201 Error Occured for the Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I wrote a Trigger for the Auto increment Please find the sequence and the trigger below.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE WEB_FE_IPO_IPO_APPLICATION_SEQ;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER WEB_FE_IPO_IPO_APPLICATION_TRG
  BEFORE INSERT
    ON WEB_FE_IPO_IPO_APPLICATION
      REFERENCING NEW AS NEW_ROW
      FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT WEB_FE_IPO_IPO_APPLICATION_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO NEW_ROW.APPLICATION_ID FROM dual;
END;
/
```

My Problem is when i executing this trigger it gives me an error like below.

```
Error(2,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(2,52): PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW_ROW.APPLICATION_ID' must be declared
Error(2,75): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

I cant find the issue. can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prefix `new_row` with a colon.  `into :new_row.application_id`.  Since you're on 11g, you don't need a `select into`, you can just do a direct assignment of the `nextval`.  I can't see a reason to bother changing the name of the `:new` pseudorecord either.  So I'd just do

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER WEB_FE_IPO_IPO_APPLICATION_TRG
  BEFORE INSERT ON WEB_FE_IPO_IPO_APPLICATION
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.application_id := WEB_FE_IPO_IPO_APPLICATION_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
```